# Hover change text on nav to italic and different color css

Tags: css, hover, squarespace

I there! I would like some help with my squarespace site to change the text in the nav bar when hovering. Style and color.

Here is an example of a site where I've seen this - vvorkroom.com

Thanks so much!

kim

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this

```
.nav > nav-links > a:hover {
    color : (1, 1, 122, 1);
 }
```

> note: change the class with your own.